# Why the function javascript give me the same value

Tags: javascript, html

Why the function give me the same value when I want it to change every time I choose other radio buttom

```
    <form>
    <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male">
    <label for="male">Male</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">
    <label for="female">Female</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="other" name="gender" value="other">
    <label for="other">Other</label>
    <button onclick="addSpan()">Try it</button>

</form>
```

this is function

```
<script>
function addSpan() {
    var female = document.getElementById("female");
    var male = document.getElementById("male");
    var other = document.getElementById("other");
    if (document.getElementById("female").checked = true) {
        document.body.innerHTML += '<span class="bullet">female</span> ';
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("male").checked = true) {
        document.body.innerHTML += '<span class="bullet">male</span> ';
    }
    else {
        document.body.innerHTML += '<span class="bullet">other</span> ';
    }
}
```

resultat 
[enter image description here][1]

Comment: evrey time return female

Comment: == true instead of = true...

Comment: try use .getElementByName instead of getElementById

Comment: see: https://playcode.io/703489/ less code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used `=` inplace of `===`

```
function addSpan() {
    var female = document.getElementById("female");
    var male = document.getElementById("male");
    var other = document.getElementById("other");
    if (female.checked === true) { // when checking something is true/false use === not = as = assigns a new value and === is checking if it is equal, also use the variables you assigned at the start
        document.body.innerHTML += '<span class="bullet">female</span> ';
    }
    else if (male.checked) { // You can actually shorthand this as an IF statement automatically checks for if its equal to true
        document.body.innerHTML += '<span class="bullet">male</span> ';
    }
    else {
        document.body.innerHTML += '<span class="bullet">other</span> ';
    }
}
```

Comment: `===` won't work here since it's bool

Comment: === works for true and false?

Comment: .checked returns a boolean value

Comment: Sorry... bad habit i guess.

Comment: Im confused I am using === ?

Comment: your link likes === but doesnt like ==

Comment: @BenCoupe Your code is good/correct (which is why I upvoted)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thanks, i think he might of replied to wrong post as the other answer uses the `==`

Answer (score 1):

You want `==` instead of `=` here:

```
document.getElementById("female").checked == true
```

`=` makes it true. `==` asks if it is true.